# std:: list (doubly linked list) unknown runtime error

Tags: c++, string, list, nodes, std

I am having trouble operating on me linked list. I have been able to do this in the past but cant figure out why I am getting a runtime error just saying that "The program has stopped working, with no explanation. Whether I use push_back, insert or any operation it errors out right when it gets to that line of code, and I can't figure out why. This is the just showing the code that is being used for this specific part.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main() {
    ttree* tree;
    tree = new ttree(); //ttree object
    tree->insert("a string");//insert a string that has been read in
    // passes to ttree insert method
}

class ttree
{
private:
    tnode* _tnodes;  // pointer to _tnodes
    int _maxDepth;  // max depth allowance
    int _currentDepth; // the depth of current node ( root is depth 1)
}

ttree::ttree() //default ttree constructor
{
    _maxDepth = 5;
    _currentDepth = 1;
    _tnodes = new tnode[26];//create Array of 26 tnodes (A-Z)
    //calls tnode constructor
}

void ttree::insert(string key) {
    int index = key[_currentDepth - 1] - 'A';
    (_tnodes)[index].insert(key, _currentDepth);// passes to tnode insert method
}

class tnode
{
private:
    ttree* _nextLevel;  // pointer to the ttree at the next level
    list<string>* _words;  // store keywords
}

tnode::tnode()
{
    _nextLevel = NULL;
    _words = NULL;
}

bool tnode::insert(string key, int level)
{
    cout << key;
    _words->push_back(key);// no matter what I do with the linked list here
    //it errors out right here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Fix the code, please.  We need to be able to cut and paste it into an IDE editor, compile it and run it AS IS.  See [MCVE].

Comment: I was going to post the error messages, but they are 4284 bytes too long.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

`_words` is a pointer to `std::list`. You set it to `NULL` in constructor and never to anything else. It does not look like it needs to be a pointer, just have it directly as member of `tnode`.

Comment: Are you saying I should remove the pointer here? list<string>* _words;

Comment: It has to be set up as a pointer

Comment: If it really has to be, then construct one and assign it there instead of `NULL`. Like `_words = new std::list();`.

Comment: @snipshow7 *"has to be"* Why?

Comment: Part of a project

Comment: @michalsrb, thanks that worked, but thats weird because I have worked with linked lists before and didn't have to set it to = new list(), but  I guess I dont know why.